# Lucene 6.2.1 - IllegalStateException "field-name" was indexed without position data; cannot run SpanTermQuery

Tags: lucene

I am not familiar with lucene . Recently I got a chance to involve in a work where they are moving from old lucene version 2.4.1 to **6.2.1** for their application.

While running with new version 6.2.1, we are facing an exception while searching:

> Exception during query field "field_name" was indexed without position data; cannot run SpanTermQuery (term=2887629129)**

In code, the field is created as follows:

```java
doc.add(new Field("field_1", "field_value", StringField.TYPE_STORED));
```

Finally we tried as given below:

```java
FieldType type = new FieldType();
type.setStored(true);
type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS);
doc.add(new Field("field_1", "field_value", StringField.TYPE_STORED));
```

With the above change, the previous error was gone, but we are not receiving any search results, getting empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you are using a SpanQuery, I assume you want the field to be analyzed. [StringField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) indexes without analysis, as a single token. You will want to use [TextField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html).

```java
doc.add(new Field("field_1", "field_value", TextField.TYPE_STORED));
```

No need to set IndexOptions here, the default will already be `DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick comment . We tried with TextField also but did not get the result.

Comment: @JayanRaman Okay, changing that to a TextField (and reindexing) would allow you to use typical SpanQueries. If it still isn't working, then you'll have to take a look at how you are constructing your query, and what the contents or your field are.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try according to your comment and get back.

Comment: @JayanRaman, I am facing similar issue , where I am not getting result after indexing in the above way, do you get any solution to share?